# recursively update object metadata in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, content-type

I have tons of files (20GB) with the incorrect metadata (content-type) causing the browser to download the file instead of displaying images inline..

I tried with

```
aws s3 cp \
    --exclude "*" \
    --include "*.jpg" \
    --content-type="image/jpg"  \
    --metadata-directive="REPLACE" \
    --recursive \
    --dryrun \
    s3://mybucket01/accounts/full/ \
    s3://mybucket01/accounts/full/
```

looks like is only copying the file itself but not updating the content-type.
any ideas how to fix this? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

removing **--dryrun** solved my problem.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

--dryrun (boolean) Displays the operations that would be performed using the specified command without actually running them.